# Homotopy type of the diffeomorphism group of the sphere.

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, diffeomorphism

I've seen in several places the claim that

$$\mathrm{Diff}(S^n) \approx O(n+1) \times \mathrm{Diff}(D^n\,\text{rel}\,\partial D^n),$$

where:

- $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$ is the group of $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphisms of the $n$-sphere.
- $O(n+1)$ is the orthogonal group.
- $\mathrm{Diff}(D^n\,\text{rel}\,\partial D^n)$ is the group of diffeomorphisms of the $n$-dimensional unit disk which restrict to the identity on the boundary.
- $\approx$ means homotopy equivalence.

Moreover, the objects above have the $C^{\infty}$ topology.

**Question:** what is the most elementary way to prove this?

**My thoughts:** I know that $S^n$ can be viewed as $D^n$ modulo its boundary. From this description, a naive guess would be that

$$\mathrm{Diff}(S^n) \approx \mathrm{Diff}(D^n\,\text{rel}\,\partial D^n) \times \mathrm{Diff}(\partial D^n),$$
by breaking up what a diffeomorphism does inside the disk and on the boundary. I know this is false, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an important fact that I quote a lot, so it seems useful to have a proof written down.

The essential tool is the following. Let $G$ be a topological group that acts transitively on a space $X$ in a reasonable way (precisely, the action admits local slices). Then picking a basepoint $x$ and acting on it, we obtain a fiber sequence $$G_x \to G \to X$$ where $G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$. In particular, if either the stabilizer $G_x$ or the space $X$ is contractible, then the map $G \to X$ (resp. $G_x \to G$) is a homotopy equivalence. If the action admits a global section, then the section provides a homeomorphism $G_x \times X \to G$.

Now let us prove your desired claim in parts.

1) Let $\text{Diff}_{T_x}(M)$ denote the space of diffeomorphisms which fix $x$ and for which the differential $T_x M \to T_x M$ is the identity. Then $\text{Diff}(M)$ acts transitively on the frame bundle $\text{Fr}(M)$, the principal $GL_n$-bundle associated to the tangent bundle. In the special case $M = S^n$, this action admits a section: if $SL^\pm_n(\Bbb R)$ denotes matrices with determinant $\pm 1$, then $SL^\pm_n(\Bbb R)$ acts smoothly on $S^n$ via $(A, x) \mapsto Ax/\|Ax\|$. This induces an action on $\text{Fr}(S^n)$ which (check!) is free and transitive. Thus picking out the corresponding element of $SL^\pm_n(\Bbb R)$ determines the section.

Finally, $O(n)$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n$, and $GL_n = SL^\pm_n \times \Bbb R^+$, so in particular we have up to homotopy the decomposition $\text{Diff}(S^n)\simeq \text{Diff}_{T_x}(S^n) \times O(n)$. Now our job is to determine the homotopy type of the first factor.

2) Let $\mathcal D_x$ be the space of *germs* of smooth embeddings $f: D^n \hookrightarrow S^n$ so that $f(0) = x$ and $df_0$ is a fixed isomorphism $\Bbb R^n \to T_x S^n$. Then $\text{Diff}_{T_x}(S^n)$ acts on $\mathcal D_x$. I claim this action is transitive and $\mathcal D_x$ is contractible; the stabilizer of a disc is the space of diffeomorphisms that are the identity on that disc.

First, $\mathcal D_x$ is contractible. Because we are working with germs, we may as well consider these as embeddings of discs into $\Bbb R^n$ so that $f(0) = 0$ and $df_0 = \text{Id}$. This space of (germs of) discs is contractible, via the following homotopy: $$f_t(x) = f((1-t)x)/(1-t) \;\;\;\;\;\text{ for } t<1,$$ $$f_1(x) = \text{Id},$$ where by the identity I mean the canonical inclusion $D^n \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^n$; the point is that $\lim_{t \to 1} f_t$ is precisely the derivative of $f$ at $0$.

The stabilizer of any one fixed germ is the space of diffeomorphisms that fix a neighborhood of $x$; call this $\text{Diff}_U(S^n)$. We have just seenm that $\text{Diff}_{U(x)}(S^n) \simeq \text{Diff}_{T_x}(S^n)$.

Note that the above procedure in fact produces an isotopy from any one (germ of a) disc to another. By the isotopy extension theorem, this implies that $\text{Diff}_{T_x}(S^n)$ acts transitively on this space, as desired.

3) Now clearly by "unfurling" at the basepoint, $\text{Diff}_{U(x)}(S^n) \cong \text{Diff}_{U(\partial)}(D^n)$, the space of diffeomorphisms of $D^n$ that fix a neighborhood of the boundary. The procedure here is just the same as before: $\text{Diff}(D^n,\partial D^n)$ acts transitively on the space of 'collars', germs of embeddings $S^{n-1} \times [0,1) \hookrightarrow D^n$ that are the identity on the boundary. (The content of this is essentially that the space of germs of diffeomorphisms $[0,1) \to [0,1)$ is contractible; you could think of this as a version of the Alexander trick that doesn't extend across the whole of the sphere, only a neighborhood of the boundary.) The stabilizer of a fixed germ is precisely $\text{Diff}_{U(\partial)}(D^n)$. So finally, we have $$\text{Diff}_{T_x}(S^n) \simeq \text{Diff}_{U(x)}(S^n) = \text{Diff}_{U(\partial)}(D^n) \simeq \text{Diff}(D^n, \partial D^n).$$ This is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I just started processing your answer, and had a question about part 1: instead of thinking of the action of $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$ on the entire bundle $Fr(S^n)$, couldn't you just act directly on $O(n+1)$ by fixing a frame $\xi$ at $x \in S^n$ and looking at $df(\xi)$ (using global parallel translation, etc)? In other words, based on your description at the very beginning, don't we want $X = O(n+1)$ rather than $X = Fr(S^n)$? PS: I guess you also need to Gram-Schmidt the result of $df(\xi)$ before you get to $O(n+1)$.

Comment: @Lee The issue is that there is not a global parallel translate of something at the basepoint (you essentially want the sphere to be parallelizable). What is true is that you can identify the *orthonormal* frame bundle with $O(n+1)$, and using Gram-Schmidt as you suggest, you can transport the discussion of the action on the frame bundle to a discussion of an action on $O(n+1)$.

Comment: What I meant is the global parallelism of $R^{n+1}$. I choose to view $x \in S^n$ as the first vector, and complete with whatever basis you have at $T_xS^n$. Do you agree that we want $X = O(n+1)$?

Comment: @Lee Yup, that's how one produces the isomorphism from the orthonormal frame bundle to $O(n+1)$, so we are talking about the same thing. I guess I just didn't parse that's what you meant originally, but it totally works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that in a diffeomorphism $S^n = D^n/ \partial D^n$, the image of $\partial D^n$ is $x_0$.

Take a diffeomorphism $f$ of $S^n$. Choose $g \in O(n+1)$ such that $g(f(x_0)=x_0$. Then $g \circ f$ identifies with a diffeomorphism of $D^n$ that fixes $\partial D^n$.

Or maybe the other sens is easier : a diffeomorphim $\phi$ of $D^n$ rel. to $\partial D^n$ identifies with a diffeomorphism of $S^n$ that fixes $x_0$. Then composing with a $g \in O(n+1)$, we get a diffeomorphim of $S^n$. And since the action of $O(n+1)$ on $S^n$ is transitive, we get by this way all the diffeomorphism of $S^n$.

Comment: On your second paragraph: if you choose $g \in O(n+1)$ arbitrarily like that, how can you guarantee that this map from $\mathrm{Diff}(S^n)$ to the other space is nice (i.e., a homotopy equivalence)?. On the last paragraph, I see a map between the spaces, but the question remains why this would be an equivalence. Note also that many groups other than $O(n+1)$ act transitively on the sphere. Why does it work for this one, and not some other group?

Comment: I just gave the idea.

Certainly other groups act transitively on $S^n$, but $O(n+1)$ is natural from the description of $S^n$ as a subvariety of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

A proof can also be found in

1. Section 5.3.1, Proposition 11, page 341 of 
   J. Cerf
   *Topologie de certains espaces de plongements*
   Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, Vol. 89 (1961), 227-380.
   https://doi.org/10.24033/bsmf.1567

or in

2. Lemma 1.1.5 of  
   P.L. Antonelli, D. Burghelea, P.J. Kahn 
   *The non-finite homotopy type of some diffeomorphism groups*
   Topology, Vol. 11 (1972), Issue 1, 1-49
   https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(72)90021-3