# Diffeomorphisms of sphere and homotopies and Smale's conjecture in $n\geq 4$ dimensions

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, diffeomorphism

Short version of question:

> Does $\operatorname{dif}(S^n)$ have more than two connected components?

Reading [this article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/how-tadayuki-watanabe-solved-a-topological-mystery-about-spheres-20211026/) on [Smale's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smale_conjecture) and the resolution in higher dimensions, I had a question which wasn't answered in the article.

If $\operatorname{dif}(M)$ is the group of diffeomorphisms $M\to M,$ then the general question is whether $\operatorname{dif}(S^n)$ is homotopy-equivalent to the subgroup $O(n+1)$ of rotations and reflections of $S^n.$

Turns out, the answer is "No" for $n\geq 4.$ And the article indicates there are classes of diffeomorphisms that present problems.

Naively, that would seem to imply that there are diffeomorphisms that are not homotopic to a rotation or reflection - that is, there are more than two path-connected components of $\operatorname{dif}(S^n).$ But that's a much stronger result than the spaces not being homotopy equivalent.

Given any $h:S^n\to S^n$ which is a *homeomorphism,* we get it must be homotopic to either the identity or reflection, by considering it as either $1$ or $-1$ in $\pi_n(S^n)\cong \mathbb Z.$ But that homotopy might not be able to stay in $\operatorname{dif}(M).$

So, are the "problem diffeomorphisms" for $n>4$ path-disconnected from $O(n+1),$ or are they just like how a circle is not homotopy equivalent to an arc, with no individual points on the rest of the circle really being "the problem point?"

(I restrict to $n>4$ only because the article indicates they don't yet know much about the problem diffeomorphisms for $n=4.$)

Comment: read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere#Order_of_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000026-QINU%60%22'%7F

Comment: @thomas  Interesting, but not sure how that applies, because my question is about one differential structure on $S^n,$ the standard one.

Comment: see here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07269.pdf

Comment: @NickL I’m not seeking the latest research. I probably can’t read it, and certainly won’t try unless you give me a summary of what I might learn digging in to it, rather than just a link.

Comment: You are confusing three different notions: homotopy, isotopy and diffeotopy. Only the last one is relevant if you want to count the number of components of Diff.

Comment: How am I confusing them? I know the difference. I consider the concepts separately and in comparison, as far as I can tell,  not as the same. @MoisheKohan

Comment: You ask if the problem diffeos are path connected to $O(n+1)$, but are you asking for a path in $Diff(S^n)$ or in $Homeo(S^n)$?  (This may be what Moishe was getting at with his comment.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito how do you know what he was asking? I quite clearly ask if $\operatorname{Dif}(S^n)$ has more than two path connected components. Not sure how you can say the path in question might be allowed to be in any other set. I mention a homotopy must exist, but that is only a path in the space of all continuous functions, not even in $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^n),$ which I never even mention. I’m honestly wanting to clarify anything unclear here, but…

Comment: OK, so you know the difference, then you also know that $\pi_n(S^n)\cong Z$ is essentially irrelevant here. (Homotopy is via continuous maps.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan of course, I mention in the question that this path doesn’t show us anything about paths in Dif. But I don’t know how much that difference is. Can it actually be more disconnected? I don’t know, hence the question.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews The point is that $\Theta _n$ is the number of differentiable structure on $S_{n+1}$.

Comment: It’s not clear how different differentiable structures on $S^{n+1}$ is related to diffeomorphisms on one differentiable structure on $S^{n+1}.$ @Thomas

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  Yes, you did quite clearly ask if $Diff(S^n)$ has more than two path components, but I found the remainder of that paragraph confusing.  And to respond to your last comment:  There is a homotopy equivalence $Diff(S^n)\cong O(n)\times Diff(D^n\text{ rel } \partial D^n)$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965261/homotopy-type-of-the-diffeomorphism-group-of-the-sphere) while $\pi_0(Diff(D^n\text{ rel } \partial D^n)$ is isomoprhic to $\Theta_{n+1}$  (See "historical remarks" here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09475.pdf).

Comment: So, there are diffeos of $S^n$ which are not in the same path component of either path component of $O(n)$ precisely when $\Theta_{n+1}$ is non-trivial. This occurs in some dimensions e.g., $n\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,12, 61\}$.  It's known that the set I just wrote contains no other odd numbers, but, to my knowledge, whether it contains any more even numbers is unknown.

Comment: That seems like a fine answer. @JasonDeVito

Comment: Agreed.  When I started writing the comments, my thoughts hadn't yet cohered enough.  I'll write one up (if no one beats me to it) when I have time.  (Most likely tomorrow morning.)

Comment: maybe this needs a follow up question since wikipedia/quanta magazine say that the Smale conjecture fails for n>5 but Jason DeVito commented that he doesn't know why it should fail on dimensions n=6,7,13,57,62 (this list could contain more even numbers)

Comment: Those are not contradictory. The space can be path-connected and still not be a homotopy-equivalence. That was my point about the circle in the question. @dabed

Comment: thanks, I agree there is not contradiction just saying that the argument doesn't work for all dimensions so on those dimension where the space is path connected one has still to prove that they are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @Dabed The Wikipedia page for Smale makes clear it is resolved in the negative for $n\geq 4.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smale_conjecture?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Agree again is not contradictory and is a resolved matter that is why a wrote "...since wikipedia/quanta magazine say that the Smale conjecture fails for n>5..." only meant to say that the sketch given in the answer is missing a step but I will give it some more thought, thank you very much

Comment: For future readers, I [contacted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Dabed) the editor who added the result about $n\geq5$ and he notes the reason is that the Smale conjecture is equivalent to the space $\text{Diff}_{\partial}(D^d)$ being contractible which fails for $n\geq5$ so failing to be path connected is weaker than needed and cites the first page of Watanabe paper as reference where it can be read this is really by work of Hatcher not Milnor and Kervaire, I will possibly edit the page at some point accordingly and if the editor provides further feedback I should include that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use the notation $\operatorname{Diff}_\partial$ to denote $\operatorname{Diff}(D^n\text{ rel } \partial D^n) = \{f:D^n\rightarrow D^n| f\text{ is a diffeomorphism and } f|_{\partial D^n} = Id_{\partial D^n}\}$.

From [this MO question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965261/homotopy-type-of-the-diffeomorphism-group-of-the-sphere) one finds a proof that $\operatorname{Diff}(S^n)$ has the homotopy type of $O(n+1)\times \operatorname{Diff}_\partial$.  So, there are diffeomorphisms of $S^n$ which are not path connected to $O(n+1)$ precisely when $\operatorname{Diff}_\partial$ has multiple path components.

From the "Historical Remarks" portion of [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09475.pdf), one finds the following facts:  For $n=1,2,3$, $\operatorname{Diff}_\partial$ has the homotopy type of a point.  For $n=1$, this is "classical", for $n=2$ it's a result of Smale, and for $n=3$ it's a result of Hatcher.  Thus, in these dimensions, all diffeomorphisms of $S^n$ are path connected in $\operatorname{Diff}(S^n)$ to $O(n+1)$.

For $n\geq 5$, there is an isomorphism between $\pi_0(\operatorname{Diff}_\partial)$ and $\Theta_{n+1}$, the group of exotic $(n+1)$-spheres.  Thus, whenever $|\Theta_{n+1}|\neq 1$, there are diffeomorphisms of $S^n$ which are not path connected to $O(n+1)$.  This case is typical.  In fact, the only known examples with $n\geq 5$, and $|\Theta_{n+1}| = 1$ are when $n+1\in \{6,7,13,55,62\}$ (see [this preprint.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.06854.pdf)  Moreover, from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02184), the set I just listed is complete for even entries.

All this leaves the case $n=4$.  But in  [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07269.pdf), one finds a proof that there are diffeomorphisms of $S^4$ which are not path connected to $O(5)$.

Comment: I ran out of time when composing this answer.  I'll try to go back and find reference to published versions of all these preprints when I have more time (or someone else should feel free to edit them in)

Comment: Upvoted, but you should use a command like \operatorname to typeset "Diff."

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip:  Thanks for the $+1$.  I agree that operatorname makes it look much nicer.

Comment: The n=4 case is still open. The preprint that you suggested has some flaw (I am unaware of the fact that if it is been corrected in the recent version or not. I had a small chat with the author in recent time but unfortunately we didn't talk abouth this).

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee:  I did notice that preprint had a high number of revisions.  But thanks for pointing that out.  I am definitely not an expert in anything I wrote in the answer above!

Comment: Why does the Smale conjecture still fails when n=6,7,13,57,62 (and the rest of even dimensions where we don't know if $|\Theta_{n+1}| = 1$)?

Comment: @Dabed:  I am not an expert on this, but presumably it's because we can show that $\operatorname{Diff}_\partial$ has $\pi_k$ non-trivial for some $k > 0$ in those cases.  Honestly, I'm not even confident the Smale conjecture *does* fail in those dimensions.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I believe this is a result of classical rational computation of pseudoisotopy maybe by Farrell-Hsiang. I think it works above dimension 4 which is why Watanabe's result in dimension 4 settled the last open case.